# Виджеты для Unix/Linux систем

Tags: linux, api, gui, unix

Здравствуйте. Может кто-нибудь объяснить на пальцах или кинуть статейку, о том, каким образом для unix/linux систем создаются виджеты? Ведь там нет родного API наподобие WinApi или COCOA для создания GUI.

Comment: что ты понимаешь под словом «виджет»?

Comment: @Fat-Zer элемент GUI

Comment: базовые классы элементов GUI в объектно-ориентированных библиотеках тулкитов?

Comment: @Fat-Zer элемент графического интерфейса (кнопка, слайдер, текстовое поле...). Unix/Linux по дефолту не имеют родного API для создания GUI, т.е. грубо говоря используется консолька для взаимодействия с ядром, а вот к примеру Windows и Mac OS имеют родной API для создания GUI. Так вот, мне интересно, каким образом в Unix/Linux делают GUI.

Comment: Тебе наверное надо читать про `Wayland`.

Comment: Видимо, виджеты - это та хренотень, которая замусоривает десктоп?

Comment: См документацию по DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Описывать весь графический стек *nix систем довольно проблематично т.к. он содержит в себе множество исторических наслоений и достаточно разнообразен. Но базовая структура на большинстве текущих систем такая:

Есть [X сервер](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (сервер дисплея) — это программа, работающая на машине с дисплеем и клавиатурой. Она взаимодействует с драйверами и отвечает за отрисовку на экран.

Есть клиентские приложения, по факту это прикладные программы, которые подключаются к X серверу и общаются с ним по формализованному [протоколу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol). Подключение может быть как локальным так и удалённым (скорее историческая особенность, нежели достоинство). Протокол включает в себя средства управления окнами, рисования графических примитивов (линии, прямоугольники, текст в заданном шрифте итп), вывода готовых pixmap'ов, а также многое другое. Кроме основного протокола существует также значительное количество расширений для него. Это всё в совокупности можно считать API-0.

Обычно клиентские приложения не сами реализуют протокол, а используют для этого специальную библиотеку, обычно ей является [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib). Она содержит минимальные надстройки над протоколом и фактически является минимальным интерфейсом, который интересен пользователю. Её С API является базой, которую используют вышестоящие библиотеки. Для большинства расширений протокола также есть свои эталонные реализации клиентских библиотек.

Выше по стеку находятся библиотеки тулкитов две основные — [Gtk+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) и [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)); менее популярные в наше время — fltk, Xt/Motif, EFL и др. Они в большинстве своём уже являются кроссплатформенными и предоставляют базовые графические примитивы такие как «кнопки», «слайдеры», «текстовые поля». Назвать кого-то из них стандартным нельзя т.к. те кто используют остальные сразу обижаются.

В последнее время пытаются отказаться от X в пользу других серверов, таких как [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)), mir и др., но пока полностью это получилось сделать только у всяких отщепенцев вроде android'а и MacOs. Наиболее перспективным вариант на сегодня для десктопных Linux систем, пожалуй. является Wayland.